# C++ Map with value that is a pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary

If I have a map of type`std::map<std::string, Person>` where `Person` is a class I have defined, the following is how I would access the `Person` at the iterator `it`:

```
it->second;
```

But what if the map was of type`std::map<std::string, Person*>`, in which case the element would be a pointer to a `Person`, rather than an actual `Person`. How would I then access the `Person`? For example, is this correct:

```
*it->second;
```

or is this:

```
it->*second;
```

Thanks!

Comment: `*it->second`. But you should not do this. If value semantics don't work for you then use either `unique_ptr<Person>` or `shared_ptr<Person>` depending on what ownership is meant to be indicated.

Comment: Why should they not do it?

Comment: Well, I think I've been having trouble with some code of mine because passing by value is causing complications somewhere along the line, so I figured if I started passing pointers to the objects and storing those pointers, then I could avoid any situation in which copying would cause data to be incorrect.

Comment: Don't switch to pointers just because you can't get values to work.  Pointers add complexity.  You should concentrate on getting your `Person` class to work properly first.

Comment: Well, I had assumed that the names of the people were not printing because the objects were not copying correctly when passed by value. Should this not be the case?

Comment: Note that `->*` is an operator to apply member pointer to a instance.

Comment: @CreasyBear I can't tell since I don't see your `Person` class code.

Comment: @CreasyBear you can store objects in your map by value, and then use pass-by-reference to pass them to functions

Answer (score 2):

Well you'd *most* likely access `it->second->name`, for instance. but `*(it->second)` is correct (I think you don't need the ( ), can't remember; check operator precedence.)

Answer (score 0):

```
Person const & person = *it->second;
std::cout << person.name << std::endl;
std::cout << person.address << std::endl;
//etc
```

Or simply

```
std::cout << it->second->name << std::endl;
std::cout << it->second->address << std::endl;
```